# Ubuntu Wayland makes Unreal Engine 100% laggy/unusable/choppy/screen tearing, but all other apps are fine

Tags: nvidia, wayland

However, on X11, Unreal Engine is completely fine and lagless. The issue is that I know I may be forced to move to Wayland in the near future, and it ultimately has a lagless interface across the board for all other applications. I would like to migrate to it and start using it at this time, but this is the main application I use on a daily basis!

Ubuntu 23.10
Nvidia 535 driver/RTX 2060
Ryzen 7/32GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

Potentially related:
https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/104382

Will likely be something I have to deal with until Nvidia's drivers are improved. Still hoping to keep this open in case of additional answers.